# Unknown lifecycle phase "run". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase

Tags: maven-lifecycle

[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "run". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase
or a goal in the format

Comment: Are you trying to run using some IDE? if yes, which one?

Comment: Eclipse @PoorviNigotiya

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using 'run' which maven is not able to recognize.
Use `clean install`only

Comment: Thanks :) 
I got it resolved Root Cause : The phases of the life cycle was not properly defined in execution tag in POM File results throwing the Error : [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "run". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved
Root Cause : The phases of the life cycle was not properly defined in execution tag in POM File results throwing the Error :
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "run". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format